# Find missing angles $x,y$ in the following diagram

Tags: geometry

The diagram is this

[image]

I was trying to express all unknown angles in terms of $x$ and $y$, and do some manipulation. But unfortunately this did not give me anything since all $x,y$'s cancelled out. Any hints for the appropriate approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice problem!

First, draw circle $FGH$ and then extend each of $F,G,H$ through $E$ to intersect the circle at $F^\prime, G^\prime, H^\prime$. Fill in the known angles, as well as their basic implications.

[image]

Now, triangles $EH^\prime G^\prime$ and $EFH^\prime$ are congruent, so $EG^\prime = EF$, and so triangles $HEG^\prime$ and $HEF$ are congruent. Therefore, angle $FHE = x$ equals angle $H^\prime H G^\prime$.

Finally, cyclic quadrilateral $HFH^\prime G^\prime$ gives $2x + 2(67^\circ) = 180^\circ$, so $x = 23^\circ$. Since $x + y = 48^\circ$, $y = 25^\circ$.

Comment: This is brilliant...simple and elegant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

We might as well let $EG=1$ and we know from $\triangle EGH$ that $x+y=48^\circ$.  Then from the law of sines $$\frac {EH}{\sin 67^\circ}=\frac 1{\sin 48^\circ}\\
\frac {EF}{\sin 46^\circ}=\frac 1{\sin 84^\circ}\\ FH^2=EF^2+EH^2-2EF\cdot EH \cos 115^\circ \\
\frac {EF}{\sin x}=\frac {FH}{\sin 115^\circ}$$

I get $EH=1.2387, EF=0.7233, FH=1.678, \sin x=0.3907, x=23^\circ$

Comment: I don't think that's right. Given $E$, $G$ and the known angles, the points $F$ and $H$ are completely determined, and they define $x$ and $y$..

Comment: @MichaelBiro: $E$ and $G$ are not determined, nor the distance between them.  I filled in all the angles and couldn't find anything that gave $x-y$

Comment: Since we can scale, translate, and rotate without affecting the problem, $EG$ can be chosen to be any line segment, after which $F$ and $H$ can be found using the given angles.

Comment: @MichaelBiro:  you are right. I'll fix.  I think it takes laws of sines/cosines to work, not just adding angles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking a little bit about using sine/cosine laws, but it seems that it is hard to yield the precise value of the angle.